# How can Bash still write to the terminal when blocking access to tty with cgroups?

Tags: linux, cgroups

## Environment:

- OS: [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 8 ([generic/centos8](https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/centos8) [Vagrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_%28software%29) box)
- Virtualization: VMware-Workstation 16.1.0 build-17198959

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a devices new policy

```
cd /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
mkdir custom_poc
```

2. Verify which device is being used as tty (multiple methods):

- Using tty:

  ```
  root@centos8# tty
  /dev/pts/0
  ```
- Getting the process STDIN:

  ```
  ls -l /proc/$$/fd/{0,1,2}
  lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Mar  5 11:25 /proc/2446/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/0
  lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Mar  5 11:25 /proc/2446/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/0
  lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Mar  5 11:25 /proc/2446/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/0
  ```

3. Add tty device to `devices.deny`:

- Check device major and minor numbers:

  ```
  ls -l /dev/pts/0
  crw--w----. 1 vagrant tty 136, 0 Mar  5 11:28 /dev/pts/0
  ```
- Deny access:

  ```
  root@centos8# echo 'c 136:0 w' > /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/custom_poc/devices.deny
  root@centos8# echo $$ > tasks
  root@centos8# echo 'a' > /dev/pts/0
  -bash: /dev/pts/0: Operation not permitted
  ```
- However, my Bash terminal works just fine even after removing access to STDIN device. Here is the output of a simple whoami:

  ```
  root@centos8# whoami
  root
  ```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [the kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/devices.html#description):

> Implement a cgroup to track and enforce **open** and mknod restrictions on device files.

The restrictions are only applied upon **opening** device files.  That's the same as for most other access control permissions such as the standard Unix permissions.

Once you have opened a file in read+write mode, you can read and write from it. Access control are not applied upon each `read()` and `write()`, that would add too much overhead, and that would likely cause very surprising behaviours in applications. It would be difficult to enforce as well when a file is `mmap`ped() in memory for instance.

In your case, the `/dev/pts/0` was opened (likely by one of its parent, maybe a terminal emulator, maybe `getty`, maybe `sshd`..., and the shell inherited the file descriptor) before you applied the restriction.

Similarly, upon forking a process to execute `whoami`, the child inherits the fds and those fds are preserved upon executing `whoami` and `whoami` just does a `write(1, "root\n", 5)` without ever opening the device file.

In `echo a > /dev/pts/0` however, the shell does try to open the file to perform that redirection and is being prevented from doing so at that point.